# How can I access SQL server using ADO through a proxy?

Tags: delphi, proxy, ado

I have a Delphi application that uses ADO to connect to a SQL server hosted on the Internet. The user running this application wants to access the SQL server through a proxy internally.  How can this be done?

Comment: It depends... usually for "proxy" people means a "http proxy", but unfortunately if you're connecting directly to the database, it is not possible to make that connection trough a http proxy, but there's other options, like using datasnap over http.  In that case, you're allowed to go trough proxies (you still have to hack it, because the proxy configuration of the internal indy component are hidden in the current implementation of DataSnap).

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing special that needs to be done in the actual application, this is a networking problem, you would have to open some ports (1433 is the default) on the firewall for the communications to go through (going out)